# Error Running jar command from shell Script

Tags: bash, shell-script

I need to extract the contents of the Jar in to a specific location. When I run the below command to extract jar, it works correctly.

```
jar -xf location/ex.jar
```

The same command I placed inside a script(.sh/.ksh). When I run the script, I get the below error:

```
 jar:  not found.
```

Both the user are same from which I run the script/command.
I am using AIX server.

Comment: It looks like your `PATH` environment variable is not initialized the same way in your terminal and in your script. Which might be normal actually. First, ensure that you are using the same shell (type `echo $0` in your terminal) and set your script header (for instance `#!/bin/bash`). Then, check your environment initialization files and find precise information about their loading order to be sure of what is done with your `PATH` variable.

Comment: @maxime.bochon : echo $0 in my terminal gives output as "-ksh". can u please suggest what would be the script headder for my script. I am new t unix scripting and I am not sure of these.

Comment: You could find explanation [on wikipedia here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29). Maybe `ksh`is more standard on AIX, but if it's only for launching a Java application, it does not really matter. Use the `which` command to get the path to the binary. For instance, `which ksh` may display `/bin/ksh`.

Answer (score 0):

jar is not found is the message you get. Meaning it can't find jar.

Do a

```
whereis jar
```

and use that full path in your script

Answer (score 0):

You can use below command inside your script

```
unzip location/ex.jar
```